# Can not add android platform to cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ssl

I tried to add - cordova add platform android and ended up with the following error:

```
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
 npm http 401 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
 npm ERR! registry error parsing json
 Unable to fetch platform android: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
 <HEAD><TITLE>Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Authorization Required</H1><HR>
 <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
 Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
 <HR>
 <!-- default "Authorization Required" response (401) -->
```

How do I overcome this?

Comment: looks like you need to provide credentials for your proxy server

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/347476/how-to-install-npm-behind-authentication-proxy-on-windows

Comment: are you added the android path in environment variables.